# Comments on Django Post won't save

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to post comments to a post in Django, but my form is never valid. I have discovered that this is because my request.method is always a GET and not a POST. I would like to allow a user to add a new comment and have it automatically save to the database and display on my post's detail view.

views.py

```
def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    print("REQUEST METHOD", request.method)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("POST")
        print(request.POST)
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("HREE")
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.date_posted = timezone.now()
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=comment.post.pk)
    else:
        print("ELSE")
        form = CommentForm()

    # Note the indentation (this code will be executed both if NOT POST
    # and if form is not valid.
    return render(request, 'main/add_comment_to_post.html', {'form': form, 'post':post})
```

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['author', 'content']
```

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    comment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    # approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_posted']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.content, self.author.first_name)

class Post(models.Model):
    run_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=False, default="title holder.")
    distance = models.FloatField(default=0.0, blank=False)
    time = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    location = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=False, default="")
    image = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, default="")

    @property
    def pace(self):
        if self.distance == 0.0:
            return 0.0
        return round(self.time / self.distance, 2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    # path('', views.home, name="main-home"),
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name="main-home"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', views.register, name="register"),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('about/', views.about, name="main-about"),
    path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name="main-search"),
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),
]
```

add_comment_to_post.html

```
{% extends "main/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>New comment</h1>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">New Comment</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit" href="{% url 'post-detail' pk=post.pk %}">Send</a>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**What I have tried**
checking out what type of request it is and handling it

searching other similar posts to no avail

changing the views function

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is the request always a GET? The form appears to be a POST.

Comment: I don't know, but when I print it is saying the request method is GET

Comment: You can check the following: inspect the html form to verify the action is post, inspect the network panel of some browser developer tools to verify that the correct post is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define else state for  if form.is_valid(): statement. So, if your form has errors, view render your template again.

Comment: Well I'm never even reaching the if statement because I don't get past the first if statement in the function.

Comment: if request.method == "POST":  this statement always wrong, right?

Comment: Yes it is always wrong. request.method is always GET

Comment: Can you change your <a/> tag with button and move '{% url 'post-detail' pk=post.pk %}' from a href to form action?

Comment: I changed it like so to no avail. I have the href there so that when the user hits submit they are redirected back to the post that they commented on:     `<form action="{% url 'post-detail' pk=post.pk %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">New Comment</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Send</a>
        </div>
    </form>`

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit" href="{% url 'post-detail' pk=post.pk %}">Send</a>
        </div>
```

Your problem is this is a link and not actually a form submit.  Try replacing that link with a simple `<input type="submit" value="Send">`.

Comment: I have made the adjustment, but now I am getting a `Method Not Allowed (POST): /post/3/`
`Method Not Allowed: /post/3/`
`[26/Feb/2020 21:23:32] "POST /post/3/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0` error

Comment: @ParkerMitchell Try changing the template to use `<form action="{% url 'add_comment_to_post' pk=post.pk %}" method="POST">` to make sure it's going to the right URL.